# Google maps API gives different results in browser vs made from http client, components parameter behaves different in browser vs app as well

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I've seen this problem mentioned in other threads but they are often using older versions of google maps and are no longer valid.

If I use the request parameters and access the following url (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?region=ca&address=10+York+Street%2C+Sydney%2C+NS%2C+Canada&key=API_KEY) directly in my browser I get the following response:

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "10",
           "short_name" : "10",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "York Street",
           "short_name" : "York St",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Sydney",
           "short_name" : "Sydney",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Cape Breton Regional Municipality",
           "short_name" : "Cape Breton Regional Municipality",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Nova Scotia",
           "short_name" : "NS",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Canada",
           "short_name" : "CA",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "B1P 6B1",
           "short_name" : "B1P 6B1",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "10 York St, Sydney, NS B1P 6B1, Canada",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 46.1427341,
              "lng" : -60.19779020000001
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 46.1425438,
              "lng" : -60.1980493
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 46.1426556,
           "lng" : -60.19790510000001
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 46.14398793029149,
              "lng" : -60.19657076970849
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 46.1412899697085,
              "lng" : -60.1992687302915
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJl_ddHCz7Z0sRQmXbPQOCT90",
     "plus_code" : {
        "compound_code" : "4RV2+3R Sydney, NS, Canada",
        "global_code" : "87RX4RV2+3R"
     },
     "types" : [ "premise" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

Which is what I'm looking for. Great.

However if I make that same request in my program I get the wrong place, namely the same street address but in Ontario:

```
    {
"results" : [
    {
        "address_components" : [
            {
            "long_name" : "10",
            "short_name" : "10",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
            "long_name" : "York Street",
            "short_name" : "York St",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
            "long_name" : "Old Toronto",
            "short_name" : "Old Toronto",
            "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
            "long_name" : "Toronto",
            "short_name" : "Toronto",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
            "long_name" : "Toronto",
            "short_name" : "Toronto",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
            "long_name" : "Ontario",
            "short_name" : "ON",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
            "long_name" : "Canada",
            "short_name" : "CA",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
            "long_name" : "M5J 0E1",
            "short_name" : "M5J 0E1",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
        ],
        "formatted_address" : "10 York St, Toronto, ON M5J 0E1, Canada",
        "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
            "lat" : 43.64109759999999,
            "lng" : -79.38122469999999
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
                "lat" : 43.64244658029149,
                "lng" : -79.37987571970848
            },
            "southwest" : {
                "lat" : 43.6397486197085,
                "lng" : -79.3825736802915
            }
            }
        },
        "place_id" : "ChIJBQZc3pM1K4gRIf5tNOFZWxI",
        "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "JJR9+CG Toronto, ON, Canada",
            "global_code" : "87M2JJR9+CG"
        },
        "types" : [ "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
    }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

If I change the address to **12** York Street in my app everything is working great and it shows me the NS address. I guess Google has it out for this one particular address. I make the request in my app with the following code:

```
$response = $this->client->request('GET', 'geocode/json?', [
                    'query' => [
                        'key' => Config::get('services.googleMaps')['key'],
                        'region' => $this->ccTLD,
                        'address' => urlencode($this->searchstr),
                    ]
                ]);
$jsonString = $response->getBody()->getContents();

Log::info($jsonString); // Shows response quoted up above
```

Where region is 'ca', and address is '10+York+Street%2C+Sydney%2C+NS%2C+Canada'. The client here is a standard GuzzleHttp Client:

```
$this->client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/'
        ]);
```

I've tried using adding the bounds parameter with no difference at all, but the components parameter did ...do something for me. If I add '&components=administrative_area:NS' to the request in my browser (which starts off showing me NS) there is no change as expected.

If I then go back to my http client and add 'components' => 'administrative_area:NS', I would expect that to be the fix, right? Well no, I get ZERO RESULTS.

Out of curiosity I went back to the browser and tried to use administrative_area:ON to force it to show me the Ontario address. I instead was shown ZERO RESULTS in the browser now instead.

Does anyone know how to make my request in the client work correctly? or know why it is behaving completely differently in the first place? Is there a problem with GuzzleHttp I don't know about that could be responsible? I'm completely baffled here.

Comment: At least the JS API has filters: `componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}`

Comment: @MartinZeitler The region parameter should take care of that, and it is currently set to "ca". Both the incorrect and correct results are coming from Canada in this case however so it's not precise enough